# Unable to assign existing PictureBox object to Object Array

Tags: c#, winforms

I am attempting to solve an exercise from a book. (with no published answer)

I need to reference a PictureBox object which is present on my form to an Object Array. (I need to assign four of them really)

I initialise the array and assign the variables to it. I then call a method within each item in the array however the PictureBox object is not assigned. (Null Exception)

I'm a little baffled as I've found snippets of code publicly on the net which show I'm doing this correctly.

Code Below for pointers please:

Main Class

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Greyhound[] greyhoundArray = new Greyhound[4];

    public Form1()
    {
        greyhoundArray[0] = new Greyhound() { Location = 0, MyPictureBox = dog1, RaceTrackLenght = 100, StartingPosition = 0 };
        greyhoundArray[1] = new Greyhound() { Location = 0, MyPictureBox = dog2, RaceTrackLenght = 100, StartingPosition = 0 };
        greyhoundArray[2] = new Greyhound() { Location = 0, MyPictureBox = dog3, RaceTrackLenght = 100, StartingPosition = 0 };
        greyhoundArray[3] = new Greyhound() { Location = 0, MyPictureBox = dog4, RaceTrackLenght = 100, StartingPosition = 0 };

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Greyhound greyhound in greyhoundArray)
        {
            greyhound.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Greyhound Class

```
public class Greyhound
{
    public int StartingPosition;
    public int RaceTrackLenght;
    public PictureBox MyPictureBox;
    public int Location = 0;
    public Random Randomiser;

    public void Run()
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(MyPictureBox.Name + " was called");
        Randomiser = new Random();

        int distance = Randomiser.Next(0, 4);

        Point p = MyPictureBox.Location;
        p.X += distance;
        MyPictureBox.Location = p;
    }

    public void TakeStartingPosition()
    { }
}
```

Also I can confirm each dog PictureBox does exist on the form:

snippet from Form1.Designer.cs

```
// 
// dog1
// 
this.dog1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("dog1.Image")));
this.dog1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 21);
this.dog1.Name = "dog1";
this.dog1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(71, 26);
this.dog1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
this.dog1.TabIndex = 2;
this.dog1.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: It is InitializeComponent that initializes the values of dog1, dog2, etc.  So call it *first*, then initialize your array.  Practice using the debugger, it is easy to see when you look at greyhoundArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the call to `InitializeComponent()` before the initialization of GreyHound array.

When you call the initialization of the Greyhound array, you have not called yet the `this.dog1 = new PictureBox()` inside InitializeComponent, so you copy a null into the `MyPictureBox` property of each Greyhound instances

Also, I think you have a problem with the Randomiser variable in your Greyhound class

Comment: Of course. I guess the pictureboxes doesn't exist until after they're initalised.

Comment: thanks, have you tried the Run method? It's really random the next value you get for each object or all the same?

Comment: I'm working on that now, all the 'dogs' move at the same rate. A work in progress indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your form's controls before you declare anything in your array, namely because your array is referencing items in your form.

```
    Greyhound[] greyhoundArray;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        greyhoundArray = new Greyhound[] {
          new Greyhound() {
            Location = 0,
            MyPictureBox = dog1,
            RaceTrackLenght = 100,
            StartingPosition = 0
          },
          new Greyhound() {
            Location = 0,
            MyPictureBox = dog2,
            RaceTrackLenght = 100,
            StartingPosition = 0
          },
          new Greyhound() {
            Location = 0,
            MyPictureBox = dog3,
            RaceTrackLenght = 100,
            StartingPosition = 0
          },
          new Greyhound() {
            Location = 0,
            MyPictureBox = dog4,
            RaceTrackLenght = 100,
            StartingPosition = 0
          },
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't access form controls in the form's constructor. You need to initialize your greyhounds' picture boxes in the Form_Load event handler instead.